# How to add multiple args in the Cloud run orb in CircleCI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, circleci, google-cloud-build, circleci-orb

I am trying to add the flags that are mentioned in the [GCP's cloud build deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/deploy) using the [gcp-cloud-run](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/gcp-cloud-run#commands-deploy) orb. The documentation mentions the use of `args` to add the flags. The build was completed successfully with the service getting deployed but none of the flags are working.

**Here is the config:**

```
    version: 2.1
    orbs:
        gcp-cloud-run: circleci/gcp-cloud-run@1.0.2
        gcp-gcr: circleci/gcp-gcr@0.15.0
    jobs:
        build_and_deploy:
        docker:
          - image: 'cimg/base:stable'
        steps:
          - checkout
          - gcp-cloud-run/init
          - gcp-gcr/gcr-auth

       - setup_remote_docker:
          version: 20.10.14
          docker_layer_caching: true
      
       - gcp-gcr/build-image:
          path: "<path-to-dockerfile>"
          image: "gcr.io/test/image"
  
       - gcp-gcr/push-image:
           image: "gcr.io/test/image"
  
       - gcp-cloud-run/deploy:
           image: ""gcr.io/test/image:latest"
           platform: managed
           region: us-central1
           service-name: test-service
           unauthenticated: false
           args: --memory="1Gi" --min-instances="5" --labels=["version=0.1"]
   
    workflows:
        build_and_deploy_to_managed_workflow:
          jobs:
            - build_and_deploy
```

**Here is the documentation screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Based on this post, the CircleCI orb cannot pass args. Try these workarounds: using [github actions](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/gcp-cloud-run-orb/issues/5#issuecomment-686179264) and [wild-orchid-watch-api-facade](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/gcp-cloud-run-orb/issues/5#issuecomment-708938591).

Comment: Did my previous comment address your concern?

Comment: @SarahRemo didn't try it but you were right the orb cannot pass args.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in args like this

```
args: '--memory 1Gi'
```

for example

```yaml
       - gcp-cloud-run/deploy:
           image: ""gcr.io/test/image:latest"
           platform: managed
           region: us-central1
           service-name: test-service
           unauthenticated: false
           args: '--memory 1Gi'
```

I haven't tried with multiple args but since it's a string I'd assume it'd be separated with space or comma like this

```
args: '--memory 1Gi --min-instances 5'
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work. The orb is unable to do that.